# In Twig, how do I use a dynamic key when translating

Tags: twig

In my translation yml file I have these translations setup

```
pages:
    training_missions:
        ...
        application_name:
            admin: "Admin Website"
            mobile: "Mobile App"
            kiosk: "Kiosk"
```

In my twig file, I need to set the application_name dynamically, but I can't get it to work properly.

This will translate fine, it gives me "Mobile App"

```
{{ 'pages.training_missions.application_name.mobile' | trans()}}
```

But this doesn't work, it gives me "pages.training_missions.application_name.mobile"

```
{{ 'pages.training_missions.application_name.'~trainingMission.application | trans() }}
```

edit:
The variable trainingMission.application contains one of the 3 strings I put in the yaml file : admin, mobile, kiosk

edit 2:
The solution is to wrap the string in parenthesis as per @Matteo 'Ingannatore' G. comment

Comment: Have you tried using `{{ ('pages.training_missions.application_name.' ~ trainingMission.application)|trans() }}`?

Comment: that's fixed it, thanks

Comment: @MatteoG. You should submit this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible! Use round brackets like this:

```
{{ ('pages.training_missions.application_name.'~trainingMission.application) | trans() }}
```

Comment: You can perhaps avoid saying it is possible and straight away get to the answer. Avoid having exclamations

Comment: @JerinMathew
or we try to maintain a bit of humanity in there, i know it's all about accessibility and i see the value, but i think those 3 words of introduction are the tiny bit left that separate this from a chat GPT tool, and they're great !

Answer (score 0):

Use array accessor syntax:

```
{{ pages[training_missions].application_name.mobile }}
```

Comment: pages isn't a variable, it's just a translation string from my messages.en.yml file. So I can only access it using one of Twigs 2 trans methods {% trans %}xxxxx{% endtrans %} or {{ 'xxxxx' | trans() }}